# Bad type on operand stack in method models.MyModel

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, java-7

Here's my model Document :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String document;
    
    public static Model.Finder<Long,Document> find = new Model.Finder(Long.class, Document.class);
    
    // Will return an absolute URL to this document
    public String getUrl() {
        return controllers.routes.Documents.display(document.toLowerCase()).absoluteURL(Http.Context.current().request());
    }
}
```

The problem is, it throws a VerifyError exception at compile time, and the only thing I found to avoid it, is comment the line and replace it with `return null`, which is not very effective.

Here's the stack trace for that exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in method models.Document.getUrl()Ljava/lang/String; at offset 13
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:69) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
```

What is this error and how can I avoid it without losing the getUrl method?

Comment: Your code is strange since your property `document` is of type String, and then you call `document.name()`, but the method `name()` is not part of the String class...

Comment: Ho sorry, I simplified the code by removing all useless stuff, but forget that part!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Ebean is trying to do some magic here.

I suggest to use a static function:

```
public static String buildUrl(String document) {
    return controllers.routes.Documents.display(document.toLowerCase()).absoluteURL(Http.Context.current().request());
}
```

Comment: It's sad I have to go through a static method even if I have the instance of that model :/

Comment: Try by keeping the non static method, and renaming it from `getUrl` to `buildUlr`.

Answer (score 3):

you can just add

```
@Transient
```

annotation to method and it works!

Comment: javax.persistence.Transient

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today. I tried to apply the same logic suggested above (use a static function for the problem method) but to no avail. I restarted play, cleaned, recompiled, and the problem went away.

Here are the play commands I used.

```
exit
play
clean
run
```